# Error with WordPress query using $wpdb get_results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a post in my WordPress database with the title "titleofpost". I try to use in PHP 7 `$wpdb get_results`, but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error().

What is wrong? Any help is appreciated.

I use the code below:

```
global $wpdb;
$leadTitle="titleofpost";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$leadTitle%'";
$post_if = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //here dies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thy this

```
global $wpdb;
$leadTitle="titleofpost";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%$leadTitle%'";
$post_if = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysqli_error()); //here dies
```

mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP 7.

You probably have PHP 7 in XAMPP. You now have two alternatives: [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Additionally, here is a nice wiki page about [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Handling errors with PDO
PDO has multiple ways of handling errors.

T**here are three error modes for PDO.**

The first is PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT. This acts much like the mysql_* functions in that after calling a PDO method you need to check PDO::errorCode or PDO::errorInfo to see if it was successful.

The second error mode is PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING. This is much the same except an E_WARNING message is also thrown.

The final error mode is PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION. This one throws a PDOException when an error occurs. This is the method I recommend and will be using it for further examples.

```
// You can set the error mode using the fourth options parameter on the constructor
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

// or you can use the setAttribute method to set the error mode on an existing connection
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

> //METHOD 2

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    log_error("Failed to connect to database", $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), array('exception' => $e));
}
```

> //METHOD 3

```
try {
    $dbh->query("INVALID SQL");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    log_error("Failed to run query", $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), array('exception' => $e));
}
```

Comment: i am on a macintosh using php 7 what can i do?

Comment: where it says or die(mysql_error() you need to change that to PDO

Comment: the code is too long for a comment ill edit it on my answer

Comment: so this code 'die(mysql_error());' causes the error?

Comment: yes, you cannot use that line

Comment: try    the code I added on the reply

Comment: i tried removing it completely but i still get no results! i guess there is some sort of error in the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184442/discussion-between-mr-programs-and-stefanosn).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php), then `mysql_error()` is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0. Perhaps try `error_log()` instead (and then look in the php error log).

It's probably this part of your code that causes the error: `or die(mysql_error());`